# getting listbox.selectedindex by clicking on checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, listbox, wpf-controls

this is my user template in listbox. i want to have "listbox.selectedindex" on clicking any checkbox of listbox. i want to knw of which row,checkbox is selected.like on click event of checkbox,it should focus the whole selected row.

```
   <ListView x:Name="listbox3"  Visibility="Visible" Margin="540,168,37,46" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" BorderBrush="Black">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="200" >

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding VmName}" Width="129" Visibility="Visible" />
                    <CheckBox  x:Name="cb" IsThreeState="False"   IsChecked="{Binding IsCheck, Mode=TwoWay}"  Margin="6,0,18,6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    <CheckBox  x:Name="cb1" IsThreeState="False"  IsChecked="{Binding IsCheck1, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

[image]

Comment: You can do that by going to the `Parent` control in the hierarchy. How are you using this user control?

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan i have updated xaml to show how i am using it. now i need to find "listbox.selectedIndex" on checkbox click event. how can i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the problem, it is difficult to know exactly what advice would be most useful to you. Without [a clear problem statement](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it's not even completely clear what you want the code to do.

However, if I understand correctly, you are displaying some data item type, using a corresponding `DataTemplate` object in your `ListView`. The user may toggle the checkboxes, and you want to update the currently selected item in the `ListView`, so that it is always the item containing the checkbox that was just toggled.

There are least a couple of reasonable ways to do that. In both cases, you will simply set the `ListView.SelectedValue` property to data item object reference corresponding to the `CheckBox` that is being modified.

The first way involves handling the `Checked` and `Unchecked` events on the `CheckBox` controls themselves, tracking back to the `ListViewItem` and then obtaining the data item for that `ListViewItem`.

First, you will need to write a handler to do the above:

```
private void cb_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem listViewItem =
       GetVisualAncestor<ListViewItem>((DependencyObject)sender);

    listbox3.SelectedValue =
        listbox3.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(listViewItem);
}

private static T GetVisualAncestor<T>(DependencyObject o) where T : DependencyObject
{
    do
    {
        o = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(o);
    } while (o != null && !typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType()));

    return (T)o;
}
```

Note the helper method `GetVisualAncestor<T>()`. It uses `VisualTreeHelper` to walk the tree back to the `ListViewItem` object that contains the `CheckBox` control that was affected.

With this object found, the code then calls `ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer()` to find the actual data item object reference, and assigns this reference to the `SelectedValue` property.

Of course, for the handler to be useful, you need to subscribe it to the relevant `Checked` and `Unchecked` events. For example:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DataItem}">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="200" >
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding VmName}" Width="129" Visibility="Visible" />
    <CheckBox  x:Name="cb" IsThreeState="False"
               IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked1, Mode=TwoWay}" 
               Margin="6,0,18,6"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               Checked="cb_Checked" Unchecked="cb_Checked"/>
    <CheckBox  x:Name="cb1" IsThreeState="False"
               IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked2, Mode=TwoWay}"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               Checked="cb_Checked" Unchecked="cb_Checked"/>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

(Since you didn't provide a complete code example, in which the data item object class was included, I just wrote my own based on your question. I changed the property names so that they made more sense, i.e. `IsChecked1` and `IsChecked2`. Feel free to use your own property names instead :) ).

The second way is a little more direct in one respect, but a little less direct in another respect. That is, assuming your data item object class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you can subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event for each data item object, and simply assign the `sender` of the event as the `ListView.SelectedValue` property.

This is more direct in that you don't have to add code that walks the visual tree back to some control's parent. But it's also less direct, in that you will need code that attaches the necessary event handler to each data item object.

An example of that might look like this:

```
List<DataItem> dataItems = new List<DataItem>
{
    new DataItem { VmName = "sagar" },
    new DataItem { VmName = "kaustubh" },
    new DataItem { VmName = "gaurav" },
    new DataItem { VmName = "abhi" },
};

listbox3.ItemsSource = dataItems;

PropertyChangedEventHandler handler =
    (sender, e) => listbox3.SelectedValue = sender;

foreach (DataItem item in dataItems)
{
    item.PropertyChanged += handler;
}
```

Note that in the above example, I assign the `SelectedValue` property on *any* property change. In my own code example, this is fine because the only properties that can change are the checkbox-related ones. And of course, this would also be fine if you want to select the corresponding `ListView` item on any property value change. But if you really only want to update on changes to the `IsChecked1` and `IsChecked2` properties, you'll need to look at the property name in the handler. E.g.:

```
PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "IsChecked1" || e.PropertyName == "IsChecked2")
    {
        listbox3.SelectedValue = sender;
    }
}
```

Here is the `DataItem` class I wrote for the code examples for both approaches shown above:

```
class DataItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _vmName;
    private bool _isChecked1;
    private bool _isChecked2;

    public string VmName
    {
        get { return _vmName; }
        set { _vmName = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public bool IsChecked1
    {
        get { return _isChecked1; }
        set { _isChecked1 = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public bool IsChecked2
    {
        get { return _isChecked2; }
        set { _isChecked2 = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```